# function copy value in js not working "undefined" value

Tags: javascript, input, copy, field, getelementbyid

i need to copy value of input with id "test-id" in 2 another input fields. When i use this :

```
// start copy  implementation   
function copyTextValue() {

if(document.getElementById('accetta-condizioni').checked){
        let text1 = document.getElementById('billing_phone').value;        
        document.getElementById('reg_username').value = text1;
        document.getElementById('reg_password').value = text1;
    }
    else{
        document.getElementById('reg_username').value = "";
        document.getElementById('reg_password').value = "";
    }    
 }
```

in this html

```
<input type="tel" class="input-text" name="billing_phone" id="test-id" value="" placeholder="Number...">
<input type="checkbox" id="acpt-id" name="accetta-condizioni" onclick="copyTextValue();">

<input type="text" id="reg_username" autocomplete="username" value="">
<input type="password" id="reg_password" autocomplete="new-password">
```

result "undefinied" in fiedls value. Why?

Comment: tested in jsfiddle and your code seems to work fine, could you provide more clearly about your case? : https://jsfiddle.net/43pf6xhu/

Comment: https://davidepica.it/progetto/birillo/?page_id=3818   try here...i dont know why dont working, field 1 is "billing_phone"

Comment: document.getElementById('test-id').value; coming  Cannot read property 'value' of null , means id is wrong here or this field doesn't exist. because i try to change the  property yo something document.getElementById('reg_username').value = "blah blah"; and it works so problem is with the "text-id" id or that field

Comment: document.getElementById('billing_phone') is the script in website..but dont working

Comment: @davidebr90 I've taken a glance in your source. Did you notice that field 1 is in <p> tag? both <p> and <input> have same id="billing_phone", so when you use document.getElementById('billing_phone'), you will get the <p> tag, not the input tag, of course <p> tag has no attr "value", and you get "undefined". if you try to get the value of input, try to set other id for input and query again.

Comment: Can i select in AND element value with id & class? or element tag?

Comment: i try document.getElementsByTagName ( only 1 iteme have name=billling_phone) but not working

Answer (score 1):

I solved my problem, code is :

```
function copyTextValue() {

if(document.getElementById('accetta-condizioni').checked){
    
    var inputs = document.getElementsByTagName('input');

for(var i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++) {
    if(inputs[i].type.toLowerCase() == 'tel') {
       // alert(inputs[i].value);
         document.getElementById('reg_username').value = inputs[i].value;
        document.getElementById('reg_password').value = inputs[i].value;
            
    }
}
       
    }
    else{
        document.getElementById('reg_username').value = "";
        document.getElementById('reg_password').value = "";
    }    
 }
```